# Using std::tie as a range for loop target

Tags: c++, for-loop, language-lawyer, std-pair, tie

I want to do something like the following:

```
//std::vector<std::pair<TypeA, TypeB>> someInitializingFunction();
{
  TypeA a;
  TypeB b;

  for (std::tie(a, b) : someInitializingFunction()) {
    // do stuff;
  }
}
```

However, this is not valid code because, as the standard says, a range based for loop is defined as equivalent to:

```
{
  auto && __range = range-init;
  for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
      __end = end-expr;
      __begin != __end;
      ++__begin ) {
    for-range-declaration = *__begin;
    statement
  }
}
```

Where a for-range-declaration is defined as:

> for-range-declaration:
>   attribute-specifier-seq_{opt} decl-specifier-seq declarator

So what's holding me back is that decl-specifier-seq is not marked as optional?

Therefore, it seems that I must fall back on old style for loops for this one a la:

```
std::vector<std::pair<TypeA, TypeB>> myList = someInitializingFunction();

{
  TypeA a;
  TypeB b;

  for (auto it = myList.begin(); it != myList.end(); ++it) {
    std::tie(a, b) = *it;
    // do stuff;
  }
}
```

But it seems a bit messy syntactically for what seems to intuitively be a rather common task, unpacking the result of a function call, which is valid in many other contexts.

Is there a proposal to add something this to the language?  Is this even reasonable idea?  Is there a better way to do this that I'm overlooking?  Am I misreading the standard?

Obviously, I could put together my own function to do this, but that's also a bit messy to use as well.

Comment: **Update:** It will probably be possible to do that in C++17 with a very intuitive syntax. [They are currently working at "structured bindings"](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0144r0.pdf). It will then be possible to do: `for (auto {a,b} : myList)`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can still use range-for!

```
//std::vector<std::pair<TypeA, TypeB>> someInitializingFunction();
{
  TypeA a;
  TypeB b;

  for (auto& p : someInitializingFunction()) {
    std::tie(a, b) = p;
    // do stuff;
  }
}
```

Or `const auto& p` if you don't need/want to modify `p`.

**UPDATE:** With the above, you can also move the elements to the tied variables using `std::move`

```
for (auto& p : someInitializingFunction()) {
  std::tie(a, b) = std::move(p);
  // do stuff;
}
```

for which your proposed syntax may not handle well. A contrived example:

```
for (std::tie(a, b) : std::move(someInitializingFunction())) {}
// Note: std::move here is superfluous, as it's already an r-value
//    (may also hinder some optimizations). Purely for demonstration purposes.
```

With that, you don't have the ability to move the values of the elements to the tied variables, as `begin()`, `end()`, etc. from an r-value container won't produce move iterators. (Well, yes you could adapt the container into something that returns move iterators, but that would be a whole new story)

Comment: What if `TypeA` and `TypeB` are not default-constructible?

Answer (score 21):

As of 03-21-2017, Structured Bindings are part of C++.

This allows directly doing the following:

```
//std::vector<std::pair<TypeA, TypeB>> someInitializingFunction();
for (auto [a, b] : someInitializingFunction()) {
  // do stuff;
}
```

Comment: "*are part of C++*" well c++ standard is not contiuously evolving. It's released in versions. So, I guess as of this date this is destined to be part for the next c++ standard -- c++17 I guess. I am nitpicking this, because sadly I won't get backward support fro c++11. Anyways +1 for keeping the answer/question up to date.

Comment: In the C++17 or beyond, this is absolutely the right answer—[structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) are much more readable than `std::tie()`.